# How to enable these lines in flutter on android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8cWH.png)

how to enable these lines that showing the structure in flutter on android studio

i tried view mode settings enabling and disablimg but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

First click the `View` tab in Android Studio

Then click the `Active Editor`

You can make changes from here

take care.